# Unable to persist session using firebase (v9) auth with Angular 15

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an Angular v15 app with Firebase v9 auth, and authentication is working so all good there.  However, when I refresh the browser, it logs the user out.

I read on the firebase doc site covering persistence that apps that have a node.js backend have a session persistence set to “none”.

Is there a way, using firebase web v9 modular method to set session persistent state to “local” within an Angular 15 app?

UPDATE: Here is my login.component.ts code:

```
// login.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, setPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.sass']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  errorMessage: string = ''; // Variable to hold error message
  
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    initializeApp(environment.firebase);
  }

  // Define auth property
  private auth: any;
  
  login() {
    // Enable local persistence
    this.auth = getAuth();

    setPersistence(this.auth, browserSessionPersistence)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Local persistence enabled');
      // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
      // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
      // if a user forgets to sign out.
      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, this.email, this.password)
      .then(() => {
        // Navigate to the home page
        this.router.navigate(['/member']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Check for specific error codes to display appropriate error message
        if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found' || error.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          console.log('Invalid Email or Password');
          // Display error message on the screen or set a variable to show/hide error message in the template
          this.errorMessage = 'Invalid Email or Password'; // Set error message
        } else {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      console.error('Error enabling local persistence:', error);
    });
  }
}
```

**SECOND UPDATE:** Thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen, some reading of the Firebase doco (who knew :-)) and some Googling, I've managed to solve this one. The following auth.guard.ts code below has the fix:

```
// auth.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthGuard {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable<boolean>((observer) => {
      const auth = getAuth(); // Get the Firebase auth instance
      console.log('auth.currentUser: ', auth.currentUser);
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        // Perform user authentication check
        if (auth.currentUser && auth.currentUser.emailVerified) {
          // User is authenticated and email is verified, allow activation
          console.log('User is authenticated and email is verified, allow activation');
          observer.next(true);
        } else {
          // User is not authenticated or email is not verified, redirect to login page
          console.log('User is not authenticated or email is not verified, redirect to login page');
          this.router.navigate(["/login"]); // Replace "/login" with the appropriate route
          observer.next(false);
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The default behavior of the Firebase Authentication SDK on most browsers is to persist the credentials and automatically restore them. --- "when I refresh the browser, it logs the user out" Can you edit your question to show how you detect that?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I have added my login.component.ts code.  I tried adding session persistence code in my app.component.ts, as I am unsure if this code needs to be at a root level within the app.

Comment: I probably should also clarify when I say it logs the user out; it may not be.  What I am seeing, however, is that on any browser refresh, the app will reload and then load the login page.  When I refresh the browser, I expect it will show the updated authenticated page (whatever page I happen to be on at the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of the Firebase Authentication SDK on most browsers is to persist the credentials and automatically restores them. You don't have to make any API calls for this to happen.

To detect the restored user, you'll want to listen for `onAuthStateChanged` events as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

So in that `else` block you'd then decide to show your login page.

Comment: Thanks @Frankvanpuffelen, does this code also go in my login component or should it be placed somewhere more global?  What fires or calls onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: Sorry ignore me, I've read the doco you provided above and it makes sense.  Will have a play and test later...